Как работает запуск корутин в asyncio?
Изучаю асинхронное программирование, и возникли вопросы.
Есть корутина, эмулирующая ввод данных:
import asyncio 
from time import time, sleep


async def waste_time():
    print("Start work...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("End work!")

Она запускается в корутине main(), с которой у меня и возникает вопрос, ее описание будет ниже.
Запуск скрипта осуществляется следующим образом:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time()
    asyncio.run(main())
    print(time() - start)

Я хочу запустить 10 функций waste_time(). Но я не могу понять, почему такой код выполняется как положено:
async def main():
    tasks = []

    for _ in range(10):
        task = asyncio.create_task(waste_time())
        tasks.append(task)

    for task in tasks:
        await task

$ python3 main.py
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
End work!
2.005629301071167

А такой - нет:
async def main():
    tasks = []

    for _ in range(10):
        task = asyncio.create_task(waste_time())
        tasks.append(task)
        await task

Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
Start work...
End work!
20.023030042648315

Предположительно, суть в том, что я в первом случае сначала все запустил, а потом ожидаю выполнения, а во втором ожидаю выполнения после каждого конкретно запуска.
Не могли бы вы описать подробнее этот процесс? Я изучал асинхронность сначала на генераторах(yield from, модуль selectors, делегирующие генераторы и подгенераторы), потом библиотеку asyncio. Ощущение, будто я упускаю что-то очевидное.
Также почему получается такой вывод:

Разве он не должен идти в таком порядке:
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
старт
End work!
финиш
2.0058696269989014


«я, в первом случае, сначала все запустил, а потом ожидаю выполнение, а во втором, ожидаю выполнения после каждого конкретно запуска» — именно так

А касательно «Также почему получается такой вывод» — никто не обещал, что таск закончит своё выполнение ровно в строке await task, в вашем случае он успевает закончиться раньше (а точнее одновременно с другими тасками — поскольку вы везде вызвали одинаковый sleep(2), предположу, что event loop и решает их обработать все сразу одной пачкой во время выполнения самого первого await task), и в итоге к моменту выполнения последующих await task в цикле вы просто натыкаетесь на уже завершённые таски

@andreymal почему первый в выводе оказывается старт?
Хотя если не запускать таски с помощью await, а остановиться только на их создании (task = asyncio.create_task(waste_time()), то вывод вообще будет таким:
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
0.0021376609802246094

Почему тогда он не идет дальше, а останавливается на await asyncio.sleep(2)?
Какой в итоге функционал содержит await?
У меня такая каша в голове, выручите меня...

Потому что event loop не может выполнять свою работу, пока вы не передадите ему управление — а оно передаётся только в await'ах — в этом и есть его фунционал. Пока вы не сделали await — таски не обрабатываются, поэтому первый «старт» вы успеваете отпечатать перед началом работы всех тасков

А вот почему печатается пачка этих «Start work...» в последнем случае, я уже точно не знаю. Попробую предположить, что завершение функции main() тоже возвращает управление в event loop и он успевает выполнить хоть что-то, а дальше выполнение уже не пойдёт, потому что задача, поставленная функцией asyncio.run — выполнение функции main — уже выполнена, и ждать выполнения тасков нет смысла

Все очень просто.
Корутины запускаются в том месте где написано следующее слово await. В первом варианте вы набили в массив незапущенных корутин и потом запустили всех в один момент (ожидание первой)
Точнее чуть сложнее именно в этом случае. Первая запустилась на первом авэйте. Вторая запустилась на авэйте который внутри первой, третья запустилась на авэйте внутри второй. Если бы не было внутреннего авэйта, то запустились бы по очереди всей толпой в первом попавшемся.
Во втором варианте вы ожидаете первую, а потом создаете вторую.
В третьем варианте печатается start/end в начале потому что они все успели выполниться во время ожидания первой . порядок правильный - один старт спереди.
Но это касается только тасков.
Корутины которые не являются фьючерсами - запускаются когда авэйтишь именно их.

Если не запускать таски с помощью await, а остановиться только на их создании (task = asyncio.create_task(waste_time()), то вывод вообще будет таким:
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
Start work...
0.0021376609802246094
Почему тогда он не идет дальше, а останавливается на await asyncio.sleep(2)?

Потому что надо loop прокрутить. await крутит луп до готовности того что ждешь. А если await нет (колбэк апи), то добавь loop.run_forever()

Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что во время создания задачи, функция create_task() выполняет код переданной корутины до первого оператора await?

Да, я проверил и убедился в этом. Т.е. заменил await asyncio.sleep(2) на time.sleep(2) и без вызова таска (без использования await task), т.е. только при создании, каждая создаваемая задача выполняла свой код полностью (Start work... ждет 2 сек
End work!). Но почему тогда при вызове задачи в цикле (т.е. ожидания ее результата) первым печатается "старт", а не сначала выполняется код переданной в задачу корутины, как в первом случае, ведь эта конструкция (task = asyncio.create_task(waste_time()) стоит выше чем print("старт")?

Старт написано перед await в вашем коде

Таски планируются к выполнению на следующий оборот loop. А он крутится во время await
